# Trying to enclose one column, but not the headers, in double quotes for python3 csv.write

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to read in a csv file, select a subset of columns, attach headers in a specific format, and output the data into a new csv with only one column double quoted. Here is the code for what I am doing

```
import csv

csvin = open('Conferences.txt', "r")
csvreader = csv.reader(csvin, delimiter='\t')
csvout = open('conferences.csv',"w")
csvwrite = csv.writer(csvout,delimiter = '\t', lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar='')

csvwrite.writerow(['ConfID:ID(Conference)','ConfName:String'])
for row in csvreader:
    b = '\"'+row[2]+'\"'
    csvwrite.writerow ([row[0],b])

csvin.close()
csvout.close()
```

What I want is the following output, with a tab delimiter:

> ConfID:ID(Conference)     ConfName:String
>
> 00AABB11     "Some title"

From sample input that is tab delimited, but may contain multiple rows

> 00AABB11    smtitle    Some title
>
> 00AABB12    smttite2   Some title

I can easily output the columns I want (in this case 0 & 2), but I cannot get column 2 to print in quotes without getting the header in quotes.

However, I can only get output where either the title is enclosed in double double quotes (""Some title"") or all strings are enclosed in quotes, including the header. How do I only get the text of one column to be in a single set of double quotes?

Comment: It would help to have example input